# C++ Visual Studio 2012 issues

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

**Updated problem #3**

I've narrowed the problem. It seems that simply including `<thread>` makes the compiler go mad.
I am not even making any thread calls, just including it.

I have tried enabling /EHsc and also disabling it.

Disabled, I get:

I get these 6 messages:

```
Error   1   error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated (main.cpp)   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\concrt.h 313 1   cefclient
Warning 2   warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc (main.cpp)   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\concrt.h 313 1   cefclient
Error   3   error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated (Program.cpp)    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\concrt.h 313 1   cefclient
Warning 4   warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc (Program.cpp)    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\concrt.h 313 1   cefclient
Error   5   error C3861: '__uncaught_exception': identifier not found (main.cpp)    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\concrt.h 4774    1   cefclient
Error   6   error C3861: '__uncaught_exception': identifier not found (Program.cpp) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\concrt.h 4774    1   cefclient
```

And if enabled (Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation & in the Command Line)

```
Error   1   error C3861: '__uncaught_exception': identifier not found (main.cpp)    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\concrt.h 4774    1   cefclient

Error   2   error C3861: '__uncaught_exception': identifier not found (Program.cpp) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\concrt.h 4774    1   cefclient
```

I did a simple test with a new, blank project, including thread and just compiling. It went fine, no errors.
However in my main project I am using Chromium Embedded Framework v3, which seems to interact strangely with the thread inclusion?

Seems odd that simply including it would make such a mess.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

By removing the _HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 flag entirely and rebuilding the project from CMake, I enter a state where the project won't even compile.
Due to this change it throws out a ton of warnings and errors from various files.

Errors such as:

```
Warning 230 warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc (C:\Users\mads\Desktop\cef_binary_3.2526.1347.gcf20046_windows32\cefclient\browser\client_handler_osr.cc)    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xlocale  337 1   cefclient
```

According to a lot of asking around and googling, the solution to this is to specify /EHsc in Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Enable C++ Exceptions = Yes(/EHsc). 
As well as setting the flag /EHsc in the Command Line input field.

However, nothing changes. The same errors come out as if nothing was changed.

**Update:**

The error

```
Warning 2   warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc (C:\Users\mads\Desktop\cef_binary_3.2556.1368.g535c4fb_windows32\libcef_dll\transfer_util.cc)    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xlocale  337 1   libcef_dll_wrapper
```

comes from the project "libcef_dll_wrapper", despite the fact that I HAVE speficied /EHsc in its project settings! Both in C++ -> Code Generation page and the Command Line

**Solution edit:**

Turns out that cmake files would override my set settings everytime I attempted to build or run the project, hence rendering any changes I made un-used, despite being set!
I was able to solve the problem by editing the project's cmake files directly.
Never used cmake before, so in the end it became a learning experience.
I have tested my project with thread inclusion now and it compiles as expected!

Thanks to all for great suggestions

Comment: For 5 years now the need to use threads by no means requires you to use boost. C++11 has perfect thread support.

Comment: @SergeyA Thanks for letting me know that! I've been doing C# a lot, but decided to come back to C++ for research purposes. I cleaned my project so that it does not include boost any longer, but the error persists. I have degenerated my code to the state it was before this error appeared, as well.. Seems like my project settings/compiler is .. broken? lol

Comment: "I've undone any changes that made this error appear" -- Manually, or through source control? If you're not using source control yet, then the second you manage to fix this problem is the right time to start, so that next time you can reliably undo your changes and be absolutely sure nothing is persisted.

Comment: @MadsM do you have to use 2012? 2015 is free.

Comment: so what happens if you make a blank program that is just `#include <thread>`  `int main() {}` ?

Comment: @hvd I have updated my problem, and yes I did undo it the proper way.

Comment: Did you turn off exceptions in the project properties? I think `/EHsc` is the default setting to enable C++ exceptions. If I turn off exceptions I get similar warnings/errors in VS2015.

Comment: `warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc` Did you check the project settings and verify that `/EHsc` is in fact enabled?

Comment: @Blastfurnace I've updated the problem

Comment: @dxiv I've updated the problem

Answer (score 1):

Make sure neither the code nor the compiler command line define _HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0.

[Compiling VC++ 12.0 with _HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 and including concrt.h causes a compiler error](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/811347/compiling-vc-12-0-with-has-exceptions-0-and-including-concrt-h-causes-a-compiler-error):

> If a source file is compiled with VC++ 12.0 with _HAS_EXCEPTIONS set to 0 and the source includes, whether directly or indirectly, concrt.h, the compiler gives an error of:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\concrt.h(4774) : error C3861: '__uncaught_exception': identifier not found
>
> [...] Macro _HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 is undocumented and unsupported by Microsoft. 
>   It may work with some parts of the STL library for legacy reasons, but it won't be compatible with ConcRT library (concrt.h) since ConcRT depends on exceptions for cancellation.

Comment: I have removed this flag from the CMakeLists.txt that builds my project (chromium embedded framework build). By doing this, the compiler spews out errors and warnings. The compiler says in order to fix that, I need to specify /EHsc in C++ code generation and command line fields. Which I have. And it doesn't change anything. same errors still come out

Comment: @MadsM The error indicates that `/EHsc` is not in effect, at least not for all files. You can look at the build logs to see the actual compile commands. It's hard to tell where the problem is without seeing the actual makefile or .vcxproj you are using.

Comment: I know it sounds strange, but I have in fact specified /EHsc for all the projects in the solution. The error persists through this. (updated my problem up top)

Comment: MadsM: this answer solved my problem as well as yours, at least in some way.  It'd be nice towards @dxiv to make it "the answer".  I would, but I can't ;)